# Reset checkbox in Django

Tags: django, django-forms

I decided to rewrite the question:

I have following forms:

```
class TOUMixin(forms.Form):
    error_messages = {
        'accept_tou': _("You must read and accept tou"),
    }
    accept_tou = forms.BooleanField(label=_('I have read and accept tou'), initial=False, required=False)
def clean_accept_tou(self):
    value = self.cleaned_data.get('accept_tou')
    if not value:
        raise forms.ValidationError(
            self.error_messages['accept_tou'],
            code='accept_tou',
        )
    return value

class SetPasswordMixin(forms.Form):
    error_messages = {
        'password_mismatch': _("The two password fields didn't match."),
    }
    password1 = PasswordStrengthField(label=_("Password"), widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label=_("Password (again)"), widget=forms.PasswordInput,
                                help_text=_("Enter the same password as above, for verification."))

    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')
        if password1 and password2:
            if password1 != password2:
                raise forms.ValidationError(
                    self.error_messages['password_mismatch'],
                    code='password_mismatch',
                )
        return password2


class TOUSetPasswordMixin(TOUMixin, SetPasswordMixin):
    error_messages = dict(SetPasswordMixin.error_messages, **TOUMixin.error_messages)

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm, TOUSetPasswordMixin):
    captcha = ReCaptchaField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'password1', 'password2')

    def __init__(self, model, *args, **kwargs):
        self.model = model
        super(UserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = self.model.create(email=self.instance.email)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password1'])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

I need to reset `accept_tou` when `UserForm` is invalid. Preferrably, this should be done in T`OUMixin`, since this field is used in other forms.

I liked answer with `form_valid`, so inside `TOUMixin` I wrote the following:

```
def is_valid(self):
  result = super(TOUMixin, self).is_valid()
  if not result:
     self.cleaned_data['accept_tou'] = False
  return result
```

However, this doesn't work.
`clean` method is not invoked, because, as I figured out it is overriden by `ModelForm`'s clean method (sorry, @catavaran).

I moved it into `UserForm`, it is invoked, but not working. Checkbox is checked.

Comment: You could override the form's `is_valid` method to reset the checkbox if the form is invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should override `UserForm.clean()` method:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm, TOUSetPasswordMixin):    

    def clean(self):
        super(UserForm, self).clean()
        if self.errors:
            self.data = self.data.copy()
            self.data['accept_tou'] = ''
```

Comment: what does `self.data = self.data.copy()` do, and why do you need to do that?

Comment: clean even not invoked

Comment: @HåkenLid `self.data` is a immutable `QueryDict` so if you want to change any value in it you have to copy it as mutable `dict`.

Comment: @AndrewFount `clean()` is always invoked then form has a bound data (for example `request.POST`) and you call `form.is_valid()`

Comment: See updated answer.  I checked it with your forms definition - works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can define clean_FIELD_NAME() methods which can validate and alter data, as documented here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute

or use this:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other

Without any sample code in your question. I can't give you an example.

Comment: i wouldn't do it here, you want to do it in your view after form.is_valid(), then modify the cleaned_data appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

I did it!

Thanks to all of you, especially to @catavaran.

I just changed value in wrong dictionary.
This works.

```
class TOUMixin(forms.Form):
    error_messages = {
        'accept_tou': _("You must read and accept tou"),
    }
    accept_tou = forms.BooleanField(label=_('I have read and accept tou'), initial=False, required=False)

    def clean_accept_tou(self):
        value = self.cleaned_data.get('accept_tou')
        if not value:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['accept_tou'],
                code='accept_tou',
            )
        return value

    def is_valid(self):
        result = super(TOUMixin, self).is_valid()
        if not result:
            self.data.pop('accept_tou', None)
        return result
```